# How can I assign a fixed device ID to a device? 

Tags: arduino

I want to control 16 lockers with Arduino and I have two questions:

Components:
1 x Arduino Mega;
16 x relays (5V)
16 x electric locks (DC12V/350MA)

Question 1:
So far I have two power supplies for it. How can I combine the two power supplies so that I only need one power supply.

Question 2:
I want each locker to have its own "Device ID" so my Arduino can automatically detect which locker is connected. This also means that opening individual lockers should also work via "Device ID", even if the plugs of lockers are mixed up. So, how can I assign a "device ID" to a locker. What do I need?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

- In answer to the first question, you can connect two batteries in
  parallel. Thus, you keep the potential difference of the batteries
  constant. But make sure the batteries are identical batteries.

[image: Parallel Connection]

- Coming to the second problem, each relay has a pin to which it will
  be connected. You can define ID on those pins. In other words, you
  can define an ID not for the door lock, but for the relay that the
  lock is connected to.

Example:

```
const int LOCK_1 = 3; 
// the Arduino pin, which connects to the IN pin of relay
//You can take LOCK_1 as an ID

void setup() {
  pinMode(LOCK_1, OUTPUT);
}
void loop() {
  digitalWrite(LOCK_1, HIGH);
  delay(500);
  digitalWrite(LOCK_1, LOW);
  delay(500);
}
```